# Having trouble with setting state to value of "Enter name" field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-native, state

I have a simple TextInput for entering your name. I want to pass this to another scene. First, though, I want to save the value to the state of the current component. When I open up the debugger, I get `undefined` for every `console.log(this.name)` I have.

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
  }

<TextInput style={styles.inputName}
  placeholder="Enter your name"
  textAlign="center" 
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
  name: event.nativeEvent.text
  });
  console.log(this.name)
}
```

Do you know why I am always getting "undefined" as the value of name? What is the proper way to set the state equivalent to what is being typed?

Is a better approach to set state only after the submit button is pressed? If so how is that done?

Comment: Try logging out `this.state.name` vs `this.name`

Comment: Wow, you did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access `this.name`, which is checking for a (likely nonexistent) name property on the component object in your case. You should be looking at `this.state.name`. However, even if you did attempt to log out the updated state in your event handler via `this.state.name`, you would probably still run into problems. From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

Finally, I would suggest extracting the name value from your event through `event.target.value` rather than going through the `nativeEvent` property.

Comment: Is there a reason you would recommend event.target.value? First of all, I get the error `Cannot read 'value' of undefined` when I try that. Also, is there a better way to update state?

Comment: IMO it's more idiomatic in that it uses the abstraction layer that the React `SyntheticEvent` provides. If it's not working for you then please ignore, there may be details about your code that are preventing this from being useful.